# Include SVG's in an equation

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, svg

I want to include some svg image within an equation. 
Until now the code looks like

```
\begin{equation}
\def\svcscale{1.5}
    A = \includesvg{AMC/3J}
\end{equation}
```

But with that, the symbol is not in the middle, it looks like that:

[image]

So I want the symbol to be in the middle of the equals sign. Do you know how to shift that?

Comment: I think you should "draw" the figure instead of inserting it. In this case something like `tikz-cd` or something similar should be considered.

Comment: Can you try `\raisebox{-0.5em}{\includesvg{AMC/3J}}` or make the svg available for testing?

Comment: @wun yeah, how can I give you the svg?

Comment: @Armani42 The image seems not very complex, probably it is easiest to open the svg in some text editor and copy the content to your question.